# Rails turbostream: is it possible to add a css class dynamically to an element?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, turbo

I'm upgrading an application from rails 6 to 7 and replacing ujs with turbostreams.

The current ujs

```
$('#sightings_by_type').html("<%= escape_javascript (render partial: '/member/spotting_sessions/sightings_by_stock_type', locals: { editable: true }) %>")
$('#sighting_added_confirmation').css('display', 'block')
$('#sighting_added_confirmation').fadeOut(2000)
```

I'd like to replace the fadeOut call, and changing display, with a css class I've got available.
However I can't figure out how I should add the class by using the turbo_stream.haml file.
It seems that the turbo_stream can act upon the entire contents of an element (replacing a div, etc) but not down to the low level of changing attributes of an element.

Is turbo_streams the wrong way to tackle this?

I could put the logic into the stimulus controller but that doesn't feel the appropriate place for that.

This is the add_sighting.turbo_stream.haml so far:

```
= turbo_stream.update "sighting_details", partial: "/member/spotting_sessions/sightings_by_stock_type", locals: { editable: true }
```

Comment: Instead of updating the turbo_frame you can instead replace the turbo_frame and add a special css class to your new turbo_frame. Otherwise you should do like you would do outside Turbo and turbo-frame/turbo-stream. Probably by having a specific environment variable set at the controller level and changing the class in the view or partial rendered in the turbo-frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript in your turbo streams:

```html
<%= turbo_stream.update "sighting_details", partial: "/member/spotting_sessions/sightings_by_stock_type", locals: { editable: true } %>
<%= turbo_stream.after "sighting_details" do %>
  <script charset="utf-8">
    $('#sighting_added_confirmation').css('display', 'block')
    $('#sighting_added_confirmation').fadeOut(2000)
  </script>
<% end %>
```

---

You can make custom turbo stream actions:

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

Turbo.StreamActions.style = function () {
  this.targetElements.forEach((target) => {
    target.style = this.templateContent.textContent
  });
};
```

```
<%= turbo_stream.action :style, :sighting_details, "display: block;" %>
```

Optionally, you can make it a method:

```rb
# config/initializers/turbo_stream_actions.rb

module TurboStreamActions
  def style(...)
    action(:style, ...)
  end

  Turbo::Streams::TagBuilder.include(self)
end
```

```rb
<%= turbo_stream.style :sighting_details, "display: block;" %>
```