How to scroll to the start of the list on Turbo with Stimulus when submitting a form?
I have a Rails 7.1 application with Hotwire. I have a horizontal list that is wrapped in CSS overflow-y: auto and scroll-snap-type: x mandatory.
This horizontal list is a simple render that is wrapped in a dom_id.
The entry created through the form is inserted into this list by dom_id via turbo_stream.prepend.
Problem: If scroll the list and then add an entry to it through the form, the scroll will not go to the beginning.
I read the documentation, tried googling. I didn't succeed in any of the examples.
Please tell me what needs to be done so that turbo_stream.prepend triggers a regular div with dom_id and makes the entire horizontal list scroll to the beginning?

I don't know how to use Hotwire for this, but I'd probably listen to events via Stimulus. I'm wondering if a turbo stream action hits the connect() action in Stimulus. https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/lifecycle-callbacks

Additionally Turbo has a whole slew of lifecycle events that you can listen for. https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/events

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77929387/207090
